# How to get the latest three SFTP uploaded file details in a SFTP server's Directory?

Tags: java, file, sftp

I have a number of text files in my SFTP server Directory which being updated on every three minutes to upload new files.

Now I need to get the latest three uploaded file's details as
 file name,uploaded time,size when ever i run the program.

Now I can only able to print all the files in the directory and it is not required.

I have googled a lot but am not able to reach the correct way to do this.

Any help will be greatly appreciative.

Below are my snippet.

```
 System.out.println("connecting to sftp...");
                client.connect();
        System.out.println("SFTP Connection established 
  successfully.");
  String path1="/sftp/content-providers/tho-e/data/incoming/scopusbk";
  com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPFile[] directroy = 
  client.directoryList(path1);
            System.out.println("Total Number of Files Found 
  :"+directroy.length);      
            int x=0;

            for (int i = 0; i < directroy.length; i++) 
            {
                //System.out.println("entered in for loop");
                Filename= new File(directroy[i].getName());
                FileDate=(Date) directroy[i].lastModified();
                //Filetype=getFileExtension(Filename);
            //  System.out.println("Name:"+Filename);

 Lastmodifieddata=dateformat.format(directroy[i].lastModified());

 Lastmodifieddata_time=Format_time.format(directroy[i].lastModified());

                //filesize=directroy[i].getName().getBytes();
                long size = directroy[i].size();

                if(timeStamp.equalsIgnoreCase(Lastmodifieddata))


                {   
                    if ((directroy[i]).getName().endsWith("txt"))
                    {

                System.out.println("File Name : "+Filename + " ||     
 Upload Time :  "+Lastmodifieddata_time+"  || Size  : "+size+" kb");

                count++;
                    //}
            }
```

Can any one help me to achieve this?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: If you're trying to detect incoming files to process them, you really need to think about how you know the file is completely transferred without errors.  Because there's no way to know that without some sort of flag sent by the sender of the file.  You as the receiver simply do not have enough information from just the presence of the file itself and the data provided by your file system to know if the file is complete and has been transferred without errors.

Comment: @ Andrew Henle  Thank you for the reply sir.But it seems there is no relationship with my requirement.kindly write the exact solution instead of this unwanted essay and i already got solution for this.

Comment: Have you even precisely defined what you mean by "three latest SFTP uploaded files"?  How do you know the file isn't in the process of being written, and the data you read from it is incorrect before you can even use it?  This is actually a difficult problem to solve in a fully correct manner because you can't tell when a file is done being uploaded.